# Embed a website in an iframe that is blocked by CORS policy

Tags: javascript, iframe, cross-domain, same-origin-policy, x-frame-options

Let’s say I would like to embed [this website](https://www.uni-weimar.de/de/universitaet/aktuell/ukraine-hilfe-der-universitaet/) in an `iframe`. Then my console would show me that this website is `blocked by CORS policy`.

If I add for example [X-Frame-Bypass](https://github.com/niutech/x-frame-bypass), the problem is still there as you can see here:

```html
<script src="https://unpkg.com/@ungap/custom-elements-builtin"></script>
<script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/x-frame-bypass"></script>
<iframe is="x-frame-bypass" src="https://www.uni-weimar.de/de/universitaet/aktuell/ukraine-hilfe-der-universitaet/" width="500" height="400"></iframe>
```

Strangely enough, it works perfectly [here](https://jsfiddle.net/29zb1fot/).

What do I need to do to embed an `iframe` of this website on any website? I would be very thankful for help!

Comment: I think you could circumvent CORS using a proxy server with CORS turned off.

Comment: @ControlAltDel Thank you! Unfortunately, I have no idea how this works. Do you have a manual for that?